# Prisma 5.2.0 error on Linux Ubuntu 22.04 (uncompatible glibc)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, next.js, prisma

I tried running my prisma code but I got this error:

```
PrismaClientInitializationError: Unable to require(`/media/ubuntu/Storage/Projects/prisma/node_modules/.prisma/client/libquery_engine-debian-openssl-3.0.x.so.node`).
Prisma has detected an incompatible version of the `glibc` C standard library installed in your system. This probably means your system may be too old to run Prisma. Please refer to the documentation about Prisma's system requirements: https://pris.ly/d/system-requirements

Details: /snap/core20/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.33' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.3)
    at dn.loadLibrary (/media/akhadkhou/Storage/Projects/prisma/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:112:9956)
    at async pr.loadEngine (/media/akhadkhou/Storage/Projects/prisma/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:114:447)
    at async pr.instantiateLibrary (/media/akhadkhou/Storage/Projects/prisma/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:113:1762) {
  clientVersion: '5.2.0',
  errorCode: undefined
}
```

and I don't know what to do

I tried installing glibc again but it didn't work I also have the latest version of node so idk if that's the issue (18.17.1)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix on this link: https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/9174
and I basically had to remove the snap version of node and install it from this link instead: https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md#deb

Answer (score -1):

just upgrade node version into newest (v 20.xx.xx), it's work for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).